# how to remove decimal point between numbers in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to remove the decimal points in decimal numbers in R. Please note I want to keep the full stop of strings.

Example:

```
data= c("It's 6.00pm, and is late.")
```

I know that I have to use regex for this, but I am struggling. My desired output is:

```
"It's 6 00pm, and is late."
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 sub("(?<=\\d)\\.(?=\\d)", " ", data, perl = TRUE)
```

This solution uses lookbehind `(?<=...)` and lookahead `(?=...)`to assert that the period you wish to remove be enclosed by `d`igits (thus avoiding matching the period at the sentence end). If you have several such cases within strings, then use `gsub`instead of `sub`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a simple pattern to find the target text, then adding parenthesis to identify the parts of the matching text that you want to retain.

```
# Test data
data <- c("It's 6.00pm, and is late.")
```

The target pattern is a literal dot with a string of digits before and after it. `\\d+` matches one or more digits and `\\.` matches a literal dot. Testing the pattern to see if it works:

```
grepl("\\d+\\.\\d+", data)
```

Result

```
TRUE
```

If we wanted too eliminate the whole thing we could do a simple replacement with an empty string. Testing if this targets the correct text:

```
sub("\\d+\\.\\d+", "", data)
```

Result

```
"It's pm, and is late."
```

Instead, to discard only a *section* of matched text we can identify the parts we want to keep, which is done by surrounding them with parenthesis. Once done we can refer to the captured text in the replacement. `\\1` refers to the first chunk of text captured and `\\2` refers to the second chunk of text, corresponding to the first and second sets of parenthesis

```
# pattern replacement
sub("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)", "\\1\\2", data)
```

Result

```
[1] "It's 600pm, and is late."
```

This effectively removes the dot by omitting it from the replacement text.

Comment: thank you for your explanation and guidance!!! it worked!